# If dictionary value exists multiple times in list of dicts, delete specific dict from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a function that returns a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'Status': 'Deleted', 'Name': "My First Test"}, {'Status': 'Modified', 'Name': "My First Test"}]
```

As you can see, "My First Test" is in there twice.  Normally this wouldn't be an issue, however, based on what I know about what's happening on the back-end, the only dict that I *actually* want is the "Modified" dict.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to say "if dict['Status'] == 'Modified' and dict['Status'] == 'Deleted' for the same Name, delete the one with the 'Deleted' status."

Comment: I don't know if you're able to change it, but it seems to be it would make a *lot* more sense if you just had a single dict, whose keys were the name and values the corresponding status. Then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: It's unclear what "specific" dictionary you want to delete. Besides adding the code of your attempt to do this, it would also be helpful to see the expect/desire result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood well your question.
But it's a tip:

```
list = [
{
    'Status': 'Deleted',
    'Name': "My First Test"
},
{
    'Status': 'Modified',
    'Name': "My First Test"
}]

filterd_list = [l for l in list if l['Status'] == 'Modified']
print(filterd_list) # Only the modified one will be printed
```